# Bootstrap tag-input and button alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esgdn.png)

I am trying to create a website, but I am new to css and html, so I am having hard time doing it. So here is a problem.
In the picture, two bars saying "include ingredients and exclude ingredients" and "+" and "-" buttons should be attached together, but they are not. Can someone help me on this please?

Here is html code:

```
<div class="well well-white well-sm hidden-sm hidden-xs menu">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="includeIngredientsLG" placeholder="Include ingredients">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="excludeIngredientsLG" placeholder="Exclude ingredients" style="margin-left: 3px;">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css for `.bootstrap-tagsinput`

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  display:table-cell
}
```

working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWeKbM

`input-group` has `display: table` css property, while the `<input class="form-control"` has `display: table-cell` css property.

If the `width` of the child element that has `table-cell` is defined (let's say `width: 100px`), then the next child element with `table-cell` property, although not defined, **will fill in the rest of the space**.

Contents within `input-group` will automatically resize — no need reduce size of it.

Comment: It is working! Thank you so much! By the way, what is table-cell doing here?

Comment: By the way, is there any way that I can reduce the size of that searbar when a website becomes smaller size?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet. I've splitted each input and addon to their own group.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="well well-white">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="includeIngredientsLG" placeholder="Include ingredients">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </span>

  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="excludeIngredientsLG" placeholder="Exclude ingredients" style="margin-left: 3px;">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

```html
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="well well-white well-sm menu">
     <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="includeIngredientsLG" placeholder="Include ingredients">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="excludeIngredientsLG" placeholder="Exclude ingredients" style="margin-left: 3px;">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But should I add all scripts that provided?

Comment: Yes, all script are require